# Not filter correcting when I’m added case for the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, sql-order-by

In my sql table, when I select data by using this query,

```
SELECT * FROM agreement_id, hierarchy_id, customer_no FROM rebate_agreement 
WHERE Customer_no = 'Kap-ST';
```

While I use the above query it filters the records as below,

| agreement_id | hierarchy_id | customer_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KAPA2 | KHIE1 | Kap-ST |
| KAPA3 | KHIE1 | Kap-ST |
| KAPA4 | * | Kap-ST |

I want to filter 1st, hierarchy_id is '*' records & other records will display later. Hence I used the below query for it.

```
SELECT * FROM agreement_id, hierarchy_id, customer_no 
FROM rebate_agreement 
WHERE Customer_no = 'Kap-ST' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN hierarchy_id = '*' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

Then it displays records as below,

| agreement_id | hierarchy_id | customer_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KAPA4 | * | Kap-ST |
| KAPA3 | KHIE1 | Kap-ST |
| KAPA2 | KHIE1 | Kap-ST |

But I want to filter my records below format,
(Display hierarchy_id ='*' records first and other records for the normal order)

| agreement_id | hierarchy_id | customer_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KAPA4 | * | Kap-ST |
| KAPA2 | KHIE1 | Kap-ST |
| KAPA3 | KHIE1 | Kap-ST |

How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY CASE WHEN hierarchy_id = '*' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, agreement_id